# Restrict/Allow file access in tomcat based on file extension via whitelist

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, tomcat6

In tomcat, i need to disable access via the browser by filetype

I can do the following

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Error Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.log</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Error Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.java</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But instead of blacklisting like this, is it possible to do a whitelist of types that i would like to permit access? like *.jsp, *.html, *.jpeg

Thank you

Comment: What you have done is just a work around, not really the right way - [look at this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/28337/how-to-block-access-to-a-file-from-being-served-by-tomcat). And oh, there is no "white listing" possible

Comment: Thanks. I cant understand the solution. I cant get any information in the internet about the Valapp element. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: That answer may be a little outdated check the original documentation out http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/config/context.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

and in the servlet:

```
private final String enabled = "^(.)+((\.jsp)|(\.html)|(\.jpeg))$";

public void service(...) {
     if (!request.getRequestURI().matches(enabled)) {
        response.sendError(401);
        return;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to apply the fix to a tomcat that already has more than 200 files of different types inside it. I think it will be a complex and tedious task to enable the servlet to respond with allowed files.

Comment: The URL pattern has illegal syntax.